# Consume WCF self hosted service cross-domain

Tags: c#, wcf, cross-domain, nettcpbinding

I do have the following scenario. I do have a selfhosted WCF with nettcp binding. The security mode ist Transport, the ClientCredentialType is Windows.

Is it true, when I set the ClientCredentialType to Certificate and installing the certificate on both sides it should work? Or is there any other option to access the WCF service across domains?

Best regards,
Torsten

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/selecting-a-credential-type says: _"To provision a service with an X.509 certificate that is used to authenticate the client to a service, use the **SetCertificate** method of the **X509CertificateInitiatorClientCredential** class."_ So you'll have to do that in addition to installing the certificate.

Comment: @Fildor sounds like it helps to the OP coz i experienced it not once.